# SQL Query for Aged Trial Balance Report in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So far my query produces customers' accounts' current balance and the total amounts that were invoiced during the following groups of days after the report is generated: 0-30, 30-60, 60-90, 90+.

I'm stuck on how to apply the payments a customer has already made to accurately reflect the amounts still owing from each invoice period. So, if some account has the following balance and amounts that were invoiced for the above periods:

```
 Balance: $200     (current balance left owing on someones account)
    0-30: $20      ($20 invoice during a period of 0-30 days prior to generation of report)
   30-60: $100     
   60-90: $100     ($100 invoiced during 60-90 days prior)
     90+: $2500
```

The result I'm looking for is:

```
 Balance: $200
    0-30: $20
   30-60: $100
   60-90: $80
     90+: $0
```

This would be after applying all the payments that have been made to this account. If the total amount they've been invoiced adds up to $2720 from the `0-30`,`30-60`,`60-90` and `90+` fields, but they only have $200 left to pay, I can get the amount that the customer has paid so far by subtracting the current balance from the total amount invoiced: $2720 - $200 = $2520

What I want to do is apply those payments to the oldest invoices first. If they've paid $2720 and were only invoiced $2500 90+ days ago, then they have essentially don't owe anything anymore for that time period. This leaves me with $20 left over to apply to the next oldest period of invoices, reducing the `60-90` day field from $100 to $80.

I'm not sure if I've taken the right approach to begin with. Currently, I'm generating the first example (balance and total amounts invoiced for given periods), without a problem, as a subquery to the next query where I am trying to apply the payments made to the invoice periods.

I've come up with a CASE expression for applying payments to the `90+` field, but am not sure how to "traverse" the rest of the fields -- keeping track of how much payment I have left over to apply.

```
select account_number,

    Balance,
    case
        when Balance = 0
            or (total_invoices - Balance - `90+`) >= 0
            then 0
        else (total_invoices - Balance - `90+`)*-1
    end as `90+`,

    case
        when Balance = 0 then 0 else `60-90` end as `60-90`,

    case when Balance = 0 then 0 else `30-60` end as `30-60`,

    case
        when Balance = 0 then 0 else `0-30`
    end as `0-30`

from (
select account_number,

    round(sum(if(charge_type = 0, total*-1, total)),2) as "Balance",

    round(sum(
        if(charge_type != 0 
            and DATEDIFF(curdate(),trans_date) < 30, total, 0)
    ),2) as "0-30",

    round(sum(
        if(charge_type != 0 
            and DATEDIFF(curdate(),trans_date) between 30 and 60, total, 0)
    ),2) as "30-60",

    round(sum(
        if(charge_type != 0 
            and DATEDIFF(curdate(),trans_date) between 60 and 90, total, 0)
    ),2) as "60-90",

    round(sum(
        if(charge_type != 0 
            and DATEDIFF(curdate(),trans_date) >= 90, total, 0)
    ),2) as "90+",

    round(sum(
        if(charge_type != 0, total, 0)
    ),2) as "total_invoices"

from
    (select  #UNION current & archive
        account_number,
        trans_date,
        charge_type,
        total
    from
        invoices_and_transactions_archive
    UNION ALL
    select
        account_number,
        trans_date,
        charge_type,
        total
    from
        invoices_and_transactions
    where
        is_carry_forward = 0

    ) q1
group by account_number
) x
```

It seems like the CASE expression and IF function might be limited in this situation. Plus even if I do figure out some formula to get the correct balances, ideally the columns aren't in the order I want them and I'll have to do another subquery to reverse them.

EDIT: This sort of approach works.

```
select account_number,

    Balance,
    case
        when Balance = 0 then 0
        when (total_invoices - Balance - `30-60` - `60-90` - `90+`) > 0
            # leave negative result since their balance should be in credit.
            # The same situation for older invoices would require setting balance
            # to these invoices to zero, since it means there's still payments leftover
            # to apply to new invoices
            then `0-30` - (total_invoices - Balance - `30-60` - `60-90` - `90+`)
        else `0-30`
    end as `0-30`,

    case
        when Balance = 0 then 0
        when (total_invoices - Balance - `60-90` - `90+`) > 0
            then
                if((`30-60` - (total_invoices - Balance - `60-90` - `90+`) >= 0),
                    `30-60` - (total_invoices - Balance - `60-90` - `90+`), 0
                )
        else `30-60`
    end as `30-60`,

    case
        when Balance = 0 then 0
        when (total_invoices - Balance - `90+`) > 0
            then
                if((`60-90` - (total_invoices - Balance - `90+`) >= 0),
                    `60-90` - (total_invoices - Balance - `90+`), 0
                )
        else `60-90`
    end as `60-90`,

    if(Balance != 0 and (`90+` - (total_invoices - Balance) >= 0),
        `90+` - (total_invoices - Balance), 0
    )as `90+`

from (...)
```

Comment: You haven't clearly explained the relationship between the input and output, I can't figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: Where does `$80` in the output come from?

Comment: There's $2520 in payments, so $2500 gets applied to the 90+ field reducing it to $0 and the remaining $20 worth of payments is applied to the 60-90 days period reducing it from $100 to $80.

Comment: I agree with Barmar, I don't understand your example. While I'm here: the presence of `round`calls all over the place makes me thing you use floats. Don't use floats for money. Never use floats for money. Use integers representing cents. Floats will kill you.

Comment: Be careful when you use `BETWEEN`. It's inclusive, so when you use `BETWEEN 30 AND 60` and `BETWEEN 60 AND 90`, the items that are 60 days old will be counted twice.

Comment: Thanks. I was going to look into that once I figured out the basic structure. I guess I need to reword my example a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT account_number,
       Balance,
       `0-30` - (total_invoices - Balance - LEAST(`90+` + `60-90` + `30-60`, total_invoices - Balance)) AS `0-30`,
       `30-60` - (total_invoices - Balance - LEAST(`90+` + `60-90`, total_invoices - Balance)) AS `30-60`,
       `60-90` - (total_invoices - Balance - LEAST(`90+`, total_invoices - Balance)) AS `60-90`,
       GREATEST(0, `90+` - (total_invoices - Balance)) AS `90+`
FROM (...)
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9eaed/11)

Comment: Thanks! This got me thinking in the right direction. So, it's just a matter of figuring out how much of the total payments someone made are left over after the older invoices are paid for.